# Is there a way to have a future complete when a Stream is "done" without actually draining the messages, in Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to see if the other side gave up and closed the sink of a StreamChannel, without actually reading the messages yet.

(I'm going to be handing the stream to someone else, so i can't listen() to it, since you're only allowed to listen once per stream.)

[posting for a friend, credit to them for asking the question]

Comment: What if you listened to the original stream, and piped all the values to another one. Could you give that second stream to the other person?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, no.

There is no concept of "giving up". If you put events into a non-broadcast stream, they'll stay there until someone listens to the stream (which is why you shouldn't put data there until someone listens, you're just wasting memory). 
That includes the done event, and you won't get to the done event without first reading all the preceding events. That's the core abstraction of a stream - a source of events accessed in order, it's not done until it's actually done.

What I think you are looking for is a "side channel" that can communicate information *about* the stream without going *through* the stream (that is, out-of-band). 
Something like that can surely be built - in about one gazillion different ways, depending on what you want, but it's just not something that a `Stream` supports by default, nor does a `StreamChannel`, if I read it correctly (I have never used a `StreamChannel` myself).